# how to get the same font effect in photoshop image

Tags: html, css, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am really new at photoshop and I created some some effect on text few days back now I Want to get the same effect and apply it again in different image
It's basically a date and now I want to modify it but I need same effect

Here is the image that I created 
[image]

I now want to edit it to todays date but I don't remember how I did.. Please help me people..

Comment: are you applied any css on this?..or this just an photoshop image??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click on the layer containing the text to get the layer style window.

There you will find a "Drop Shadow" option than you need to click and check. The settings that I would guess for the image you posted are

Distance: 0
Spread and Size vary depending on the size of your text

[image]

You can save the layer style by clicking "New style" in the layer style window. This will allow you to re-use the same settings.

To use a saved layer style go to Styles in the layer style window and choose from the styles list.